# What's the difference between echo " ok " and echo $" ok "?

Tags: bash

When I was reading the scripts in `/etc/init.d`, I noticed that they used `echo` in this way:

```
echo $"$prog not running"
```

instead of:

```
echo "$prog not running"
```

Can anyone tell me what the difference is?

```
etc/init.d/autofs:    echo $"$prog not running"
/etc/init.d/autofs:   echo $"Reloading maps"
/etc/init.d/autofs:   echo $"Usage: $0 {start|forcestart|stop|status|restart|force-reload|forcerestart|reload|condrestart|try-restart}"
/etc/init.d/avahi-daemon: echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart}"
/etc/init.d/bluetooth:  echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
/etc/init.d/cgred:      echo $"Reloading rules configuration..."
/etc/init.d/cgred:    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|reload}"
/etc/init.d/cpuspeed:    echo $2 > $cpu/cpufreq/$1
/etc/init.d/cpuspeed:    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
/etc/init.d/crond:        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload}"
/etc/init.d/cups: echo $"Usage: $prog {start|stop|restart|restartlog|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|status}" 
/etc/init.d/ebtables: echo $"Usage $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|save|status}"
/etc/init.d/firstboot:    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
```

Comment: It's also used to offer translation depending on your `locale`, when one is available: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#i18nl10n

Comment: ^was just about to share this

Comment: @GrantMooney: that question is about `$'\t\f\n\v\032'` etc, which is quite different from `$"\t\f\n\v\032"`, isn't it?

Comment: Also, in the Bash manual [Locale translation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation).  _A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign (‘$’) will cause the string to be translated according to the current locale. If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted._